# $A$ be closed in $X$ , $U \subseteq A$ is open in $A$ , $V$ be open in $X$ s.t. $U \subseteq V$ , then is $U \cup (V\setminus A)$ open in $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space , $A$ be closed in $X$ , $U \subseteq A$ is open in $A$ , $V$ be an open subset of $X$ such that $U \subseteq V$ , then is it true that $U \cup (V\setminus A)$ is open in $X$ ? I can only get that $V\setminus A$ is open in $X$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $U$ is open in $A$, $U=W\cap A$ for some open set $W$ in $X$. Let $G=V\cap W$; $G$ is open in $X$, and $G\cap A=V\cap (W\cap A)=V\cap U=U$. Now

$$\begin{align*}
U\cup (V\setminus A)&=(G\cap A)\cup\big(V\cap(X\setminus A)\big)\\
&=(V\cap W\cap A)\cup\big((V\cap(X\setminus A)\big)\\
&=V\cap\big((W\cap A)\cup(X\setminus A)\big)\\
&=V\cap\big(W\cup(X\setminus A)\big)\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the last step follows from the fact that $W\setminus A\subseteq X\setminus A$. Finally, $V,W$, and $X\setminus A$ are all open in $X$, so $U\cup(V\setminus A)$ is as well.

Comment: why is $W\cap(V \cap A)=W \cap A$ ?

Comment: I think it could go like this : $G\cap A=W \cap V \cap A=(W\cap A)\cap V=U \cap V=U$

Comment: @user228169: $A\subseteq V$, so $V\cap A=A$. Your calculation also works.

Comment: How is $A$ a subset of $V$ ?

Comment: @user228169: Sorry, you're right. I'm working on a small mobile device and misremembered which set was which. It'll take me a couple of minutes to fix it.

Comment: No problem :) Thank you

Comment: The rest of your proof looks okay though

Comment: @user228169: You're welcome; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $U\cup V\setminus A=U\cup V\cap A^C$ is open if the complement is closed.

Consider the complement:

$$U^C\cap (V\cap A^C)^C=U^C\cap V^C\cup A$$
then since $U\subset V$ we have that $V^C\subset U^C$ hence the above becomes $V^C\cup A$ which is closed in $X$.